# Finding Upper and Lower Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Find Upper and Lower Bounds of $\{\frac{m}{2^n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Due to the definition $n$ can be constant and $m$ can grow and vice versa, so if $n=1$ and $m\rightarrow\infty$ the upper bound is $\infty$.

Now if $m=1$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ the lower bound is $0$
Am I right?

Comment: What do upper and lower bound mean exactly? As you showed, your set doesn't have a real upper bound. Because all member of your set is non-negative, all negative number is its lower bound. Indeed, 0 is the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Both bounds are right. ..

Comment: As one more observation, the set is actually dense in $(0,\infty)$. The set is also known as the (positive) [dyadic rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).